# Can we roll back to my changes on the Uncertainty Principle question?

Tags: discussion

RE: [How do Christians understand the omniscience of God in relation to the Uncertainty Principle?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1682/4)

I know Caleb's answer is good, but it still is based on the assumption that Christians care about the Uncertainty Principle.  It seems to me that the first re-openers were in favor of the question pre-changes and the last three re-openers (me included) were in favor of the question post-changes.

Like on programmers.SE we can't just assume a question is OK because it has the word 'Christians' in it.

The question itself would be comparing apples to oranges if it truly meant does the Uncertainty Principle conflict with Divine Law.  You can only argue natural things on the natural plane and divine things on the divine plane.

Catholics believe that Eternal and Divine Law supersedes natural and human law and I'd think that other Christians would as well.

So what purpose could there be in answering a question that uses aspects of natural law to attempt to disprove aspects of divine law.

The original (and present) question is really two questions depending on how you look at it. I see it as an attempt to conflate natural and divine law.

Comment: "Catholics believe that Eternal and Divine Law supersedes natural and human law and I'd think that other Christians would as well." If you ever go to northern Ireland, don't say this out loud.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'd like to hear what the folks who run the Vatican Observatory have to say about this.

Answer (score 5):

The question came from somebody who does not believe in divine law and thus should not be expected to understand how to word a question any other way. I think it's perfectly valid to ask a question about how Christians deal with natural law. You can explain in an answer how you think natural and divine law are to relate to each other, but I don't think we need to change the assumption in the question. It's a common one that non-Christians make and should be addressed as such.

I'm not attached to my version of the edited question, but I don't think the your version was what the OP and in mind and we should respect his question, even if it carries assumptions you or I wouldn't make.